# How to apply Blink animation or effect on old android devices?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-animation

I used the code posted below to do blink animation, but this code is still buggy and if the user click 2 times on the button, the blink becomes faster. as well as stopping the thread is not effective.

```
boolean myThreadAlive = false;
private void blink(final View txt){

    if(myBestThread != null){
        if(!myThreadAlive) {
            myThreadAlive = false;
            if (myBestThread.isAlive()) {

                myBestThread.interrupt();
                try {
                    myBestThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    myBestThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in milissegunds
            myThreadAlive= true;
            while(myThreadAlive) {
                try {Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch(Exception e){}
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}});
        }
    });
    myBestThread.start();
}
```

any other solutions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use animation class to achieve this effect just create a anim folder in your res directory if not and create a blink.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="100"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        />
</set>
```

and then in your jave whatever you want to animate just call this

```
  Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.blink);
  textView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Just call these line inside onCLick or whenever you want your animation to start also in blink.xml you can change the duration to make your animation slow or fast

Comment: In Android documentation at this link http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/index.html Animation supported since Android 4.0 and later , thats why i used threads

Comment: Buddy i am using Animation class look here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) It is present from API level 1 at least give it a try and what Minimum API level you are working on ?

Comment: Always happy to help , And thanks for your code too I never imagined VISBILITY_STATE can be use in such an aggressive Manner :D